# Query for select data by DATE in odbc database

Tags: php, ms-access

can anyone tell me how to select data by date in MS.ACCESS database using PHP?
I'm trying to select data for example (absent = 14/06/2012 13:00:00) using a wildcard (absent = 14/06/2012*)

Here are my query

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM absent WHERE id = $id AND absent LIKE '#14/06/2012#'"
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $sql);
```

absent field have a Date (General Date) Type. while id = AutoNumber.

I got no result, using that query. Where is my mistake?

already trying this

```
absent = #14/06/2012#
absent = '14/06/2012*'
```

but not success.

**EDIT**
Well, i have succedd but not using a wild card. Here are my solution, I'm using a range date to limit the search

```
WHERE absent >= #14/06/2012 AND absent < #15/06/2012#;
```

Damn you Ms-Access!

Comment: absent is a DATE format?

Comment: @ElzoValugi yes absent is a DATE format, my question, how to select data by date using a wildcard with PHP? can you help me? I'm stuck, already trying all possibility.

Comment: You are going to run into problems when day <= 12. Access will then treat day as month. Try it. In MS Access, you can use between. So `WHERE absent between #2012/06/14# AND #2012/06/15#;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't try my answers, since I don't have php available, but here are a few ideas 
(assuming that Absent is a Date field).

- LIKE makes a string comparison, so I would not include the # when using LIKE.
- for the same reason you definitely should include the quotes `'` or `"` otherwise you will get a division
- This is all US  products, so I would try dates in mm/dd/yyyy format

There fore my guess would be `absent LIKE '06/04/2012*'`

Other - perhaps less efficient, but safer - criteria could be:

```
...AND day(absent) = 14 AND month(absent) = 6 AND year(absent) = 2012
```

or

```
... AND Format(Absent, "dd\/mm\/yyyy") = "14/06/2012"
```

Good luck

Answer (score 7):

When you query a datetime field in MS Access via ODBC the ODBC driver converts it to a timestamp for example :

```
select * from table where col=#2012-06-15#
```

This is convert into {ts '2012-06-15 00:00:00'} so you will only get a match where that value is true.

Your answer using a range is better however you should really use :-

```
select * from table where col>{d '2012-06-15'} and col<{d '2012-06-16'}
```

Using an ODBC format of `{d 'yyyy-mm-dd'}` will mean that your code will be portable to most other ODBC driver not just MS Access.

Comment: I'm querying a dbase III file and using {d 'yyyy-mm-dd'} works for me.  Trying #yyyy-mm-dd# results in an error message stating that I'm missing the operand.

Comment: This little tidbit: {d '2012-06-15'} << gold. THANK YOU. Finding info about ODBC quirks is a tad challenging and this solved my issue after much searching.

Answer (score 2):

You have included two types of delimiter, both string and date. That query in MS Access would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM absent WHERE id = $id AND absent = #2012/06/14#"
```

It is best to use a year month day format as it avoids any ambivalence from locale formats.